# React Native 0.64 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile

I'm installing a new project with a bunch of modules with **React Native 0.64**. I can do a **pod install** without troubles, but when I want to make my app running (with react-native run-ios or with XCode) this error occured on **XCode** :

```
/Users/thomas/Desktop/Dev/Mobile/appname/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: readlink: command not found
/Users/thomas/Desktop/Dev/Mobile/appname/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: dirname: command not found
/Users/thomas/Desktop/Dev/Mobile/appname/node_modules/react-native/scripts/generate-specs.sh: line 27: cd: : No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

This one on **react-native run-ios** :

```
The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution [CP-User]\ Generate\ Specs /Users/thomas/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-aqbmfgqjkshyqmaprdvggqaeqjrp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/**FBReactNativeSpec**.build/Script-A319AA7F2B7AAE771AE63D66A0049241.sh
```

Note that I don't have a '**scripts**' folder in my **node_modules/react-native** (I just have assets, normalize-color and polyfills folders). I've tried to remove node-modules and reinstall it.

**My specs are :**

**iOS Big Sur** v. 11.2.3

**XCode** v.12.3

**React Native** v.0.64

**CocoaPods** v. 1.10.1

**Node** v. 12.14.1

Any help ? Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: I didn't really solve it. I've created a new project with React native v.0.63.3 and the same version of Cocoapods. After that, all works nicely

Comment: Got the same issue. My Mac has M1 chip. what is your Macbook details?

Comment: Check below answer by @khanakia

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution after hours of debugging you need to modify this file for now.

1. Edit this file `/node_modules/react-native/React/FBReactNativeSpec/../../scripts/generate-specs.sh`
2. Add this line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`
3. Then run the project using **Xcode** it will work 100%

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is correct but in that case, you are editing the inside the node modules. So rather than just enter this command in your terminal

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```